# I want to drop a replication slot which is being used currently

Tags: postgresql

I want to drop the replication slot with:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot("the_slot")
```

This slot is currently in used, so `pg_drop_replication_slot()` will not work directly.

Is there a way to disconnect the replicator from within PostgreSQL, either directly or indirectly (by dropping roles, ... - anything that would work)? In my situation, I am unable to stop the replicator process, as I don't have the rights to do so.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what access you have.

If you have shell access to the server or superuser privileges, you can do it.

- From the shell, you could lock out the replication client via `pg_hba.conf` and restart the server.
- As a superuser, you can kill the WAL sender process with the `pg_terminate_backend` function and drop the replication slot before the client can reconnect.

But these are both bad ideas. You should stop the replication client. If you cannot personally do that, invoke the powers that can.